# Dynamic SQL isn't updating table

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

So I need to basically get the count of every table in a database daily and insert those counts into a separate database for analysis and reporting purposes. The table the counts need to be inserted into has a column named after each table in the first database. For some reason, the columns aren't being updated with the counts for their respective tables. If I change the @TableName variable to the a single table name, the count for the last table is correctly updated, so it appears to be an issue with that specific variable. My SQL is below. I have another table with all the table names and an auto increment column that the table names are selected from. If I print the @TableName and @row_count variables instead of trying to update the table, they appear to print the correct table and row counts. Ideas?

```
DECLARE @Count int;
DECLARE @TableCount int;
DECLARE @TableName varchar(255);
DECLARE @row_count int;
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(MAX);

SET @TableCount = 1;

SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM db1.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'db1';

INSERT INTO db2.[dbo].[row_counts] ([type])
VALUES('total');

WHILE @TableCount <= @Count
BEGIN

SELECT @TableName = [TableName] FROM db2.[dbo].[ListofTables] WHERE TableNumber = @TableCount;

SELECT @SQLString = N'SELECT @CountOUT = COUNT(*) FROM db1.[dbo].[' + @TableName + ']';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@CountOut int OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @CountOUT=@row_count OUTPUT;

UPDATE [db2].[dbo].[row_counts]

SET @TableName = @row_count

WHERE creation_time = (SELECT MAX(creation_time) FROM [db2].[dbo].[row_counts]);

SET @TableCount = @TableCount + 1;
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

I didn't attempt to follow your logic, but the following caught my eye:

```
   ... UPDATE [db2].[dbo].[row_counts] SET @TableName = @row_count...
```

This is only updating @TableName variable.
To update the table, you need to SET one of the table columns, not a variable.

HTH

Comment: I was hoping I could use the @TableName variable to specify the column, but it doesn't sound like it. I'll try reworking that and see what I come up with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the rows in all the tables is expensive and complicated.  How about

```
select schema_name(o.schema_id) schemaName, object_name(o.object_id) tableName , p.rows
from 
sys.objects o
join sys.partitions p
  on o.object_id = p.object_id
where index_id in (0,1)
  and o.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot, too. Thank you. The only reason I'm counting everything is because this server is only used for an ETL tool and I'm the only person who has access to it. It's not a backend for any application.

Comment: In this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partitions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 it says that the rowcount is approximate, do you know what circumstances it may not be entirely accurate?  I have used this technique in the past and it has always produced accurate results.